Is Ahlfors treatment of differentials in integrals rigorous enough?
I'm studying Complex Analysis from Ahlfors and also studying analysis on manifolds, where we study differential forms. Here, differential forms are, in a way, multilinear alternate maps that we can integrate, when studying ahlfors I can see that, in some way, these are the same object, as in his book we have things like exact differentials and locally exact too. In other way, in reading Ahlfors I feel like these differentials are some "calculus-like" objects, that we manipulate without rigour, is it possible to define differentials without speaking about multilinear and still be rigorous?
I mean, what does Ahlfors mean when he say in page 163 "... we pass to the differential $$f\,dz=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}dy\right)+i\left(-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}dx+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dy\right)."$$
and the conjugate differentials too, or when he say "...we can write $\zeta=z_0+re^{i\theta},\,d\zeta=ire^{i\theta}d\theta$..." in page 134.
I can see that is "true", but only in an intuition sense, as in calculus when we treat $dx$ like small variation. I also can see in a differential forms way, but this is not how was defined in this book, so I want to understand what does he mean with that.

You find zillions of MSE post claiming that "lack of rigor" and discussing at length why there is none. I am only writing that comment because a master like Ahlfors doesn't need to meet those requirements and still do it right. If you know what differental forms are you could write his expressions in terms of those to check it yourself.

If you've studied differential forms rigorously, then you'll find that Ahlfors is doing nothing different (other than suppressing the pedantic definitions). All you need to do is work with complex coefficients. With $z=x+iy$, you have $dz=dx+i,dy$, and if $f=u+iv$, then $df=du+i,dv$. I don't remembering that Ahlfors writes $d=\partial+\bar\partial$, but this becomes useful on Riemann surfaces and in higher dimensions. (See, for example, Forster's Riemann Surfaces book.)
